# Custom Toast Cancel not working

Tags: android, android-layout, toast

I have seen a number of questions on cancelling toast. None of them is working.

I have a custom Toast. The code for that is all but one line same as http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

The difference is as follows.

1. The toast variable is defined as a class variable
2. The entire java code is written in a method.
3. In the start of this method, I have added the following line to cancel the toast.

   ```
   if (toast!=null){
       toast.cancel();
   }
   ```

The method is called when user selects (onClick) the view/layout. The issue is when the user selects few times, the toast will get queued up (the toast.cancel is not working).

Any solutions?

[update]
I tried making toast object a static variable. Still dont work.

Comment: Did you check that toast.cancel is actually being called? If you never assign toast, toast will be null and toast.cancel() will never be called.

Comment: @Mike-dg Yes. I checked in debugger and the code is reaching there. However, toast.cancel() has no effect for the toast. [update] checked again with Log message. Yes it is definetely reaching inside the if statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android cancel Toast when exiting the app and when toast is being shown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I created a Custom Dialog so that the user is blocked from doing anything else (and avoids multiple toasts popping up). Added a onClick Listener Event to close the dialog when user clicks the same.

Sad that Toast.cancel() doesn't work.

Comment: `Toast.cancel()` absolutely works - check [related answer with sample Github gist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098151/android-cancel-toast-when-exiting-the-app-and-when-toast-is-being-shown)

Answer (score 7):

I suffered from same issue (custom toast queuing up) and found a solution. It worked fine in my case.

Having custom toast object `initially set to null`.

- If this is null, create new custom toast object with "new".
- As far as you are in same activity, don't "new" to create new object. Instead, use that object. Since `setText()` won't work in this case, use `setView()` as you do with your custom toast.
- With this way `show(), cancel(), show(), cancel()` worked exactly as I expect. No delay, no queuing.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in above code `toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);`
in that u use `toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`
or se the particular time.Toast is cancelled automatically.we can't cancel it

Comment: Well... Toast.LENGTH_SHORT will make it shorter time. But that is not helping the problem. I dont want to make it too small that the user wont be able to see the message. In the documentation for Toast, there is a cancel() method. Not sure why that is not working.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code for custom text:

```
LayoutInflater mInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.tost_layout,null);
Toast toast=new Toast(this);
toast.setView(view);
toast.show();
```